# Circular dependencies in Maven and horrible structure of project

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem with maven. I have a huge multi-module project with limited possibilities to change the structure of it.

So, let's say I have 3 modules: A,B,C.

- A is a parent of B and C.
- C uses classes from B, so we have a B as a dependency in C's POM file.
- B doesn't need to have a C as a dependency to be successfully compiled.

For now, there aren't any problems.

Unfortunately, B uses C during the runtime (spring, ioc, ...), so someone added C as B's dependency, so we have a horrible cycle in Maven. Build finishes with failure (something like "cycle detected" in log).

I would like to keep it this way (provide somehow C dependency in B module) as I need to compile and deliver B with all needed JAR archives (including JARs from C).

Can I somehow build C and copy its JARs to B's target directory after the full compilation of B? Is there a plugin or tool which can be used by maven to do this?

If this post is not clear, I will try to describe it in more details.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Create D. Move dependencies to D. Make B and C depend on D.

Comment: Thank you,it sounds great.  Unfortunately, the project has multiple modules and I am afraid I cannot change its structure. Is there a way to solve my problem without reorganising the structure of full project?

Comment: Maven is an automated build tool. You are suggesting manually hacking the build process. This is not the solution.

Comment: I suggest you look into profiles which will allow you to use C only when running, and not use it when compiling B.

Comment: First I would like to suggest that you think about your design which I assume is simply wrong. This is foundation of your problem. Any other think things like profiles etc. are not really a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there are two issues:

1. How to tell Maven about a runtime-only dependency between artifacts.
2. How to get Maven to leverage the dependency to pull together all the relevant dependencies.

Maven has a feature of dependency management that allows you to inform maven of such nuances using the "scope" element of the dependency element. In this case, I think you want

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

See the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). In particular:

> runtime - This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

Proper utilization of the runtime `scope` should resolve the circular dependency issue.

Regarding the second issue, you have not supplied enough information to provide a definitive answer. However, you almost certainly want to use a maven plugin in order to leverage maven's information about the dependencies. For example, if you want to produce a single "fat" jar that contains everything, you want to look at maven-shade-plugin. Another option is maven-assembly-plugin, which is extremely flexible and can include all dependencies in the assembly. There are other plugins that excel at handling various other common circumstances. You may want to formulate a separate question if you have problems with how to use a specific plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it. From C's pom file:

```
 <profile>
    <id>compile</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           use B here but do not use in the main dependencies section
        </dependency>
          + other dependencies
      </dependencies>
  </build>
</profile>
```

For example you can compile C module using `mvn compile -Pcompile`

From B's pom file:

```
 <profile>
    <id>run</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           use C here but do not use in the main dependencies section
        </dependency>
          + other dependencies
      </dependencies>
  </build>
</profile>
```

you run B module using `mvn yourcommandforrunning -Prun`

In this way you can escape the cyclic dependencies issue.